# How can this be packed into a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

The query and the fetching are working properly, but it's too repetitive, I tried (applying some tutorials on for loops) but can't seem to figure out.

```
    <div class="spctcls">
      <div class="artc_cnt">
        <a class="art_liga" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[0]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[0]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[0]['id'] ?>">
          <div class="artc_foto">
            <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulos[0]['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
          </div>
          <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[0]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[0]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[0]['id'] ?>">
            <?= $articulos[0]['titulo']; ?>
          </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="spctcls">
      <div class="artc_cnt">
        <a href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[1]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[1]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[1]['id'] ?>">
          <div class="artc_foto">
            <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulos[1]['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
          </div>
          <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[1]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[1]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[1]['id'] ?>">
            <?= $articulos[1]['titulo']; ?>
          </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="spctcls">
      <div class="artc_cnt">
        <a href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[2]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[2]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[2]['id'] ?>">
          <div class="artc_foto">
            <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulos[2]['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
          </div>
          <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[2]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[2]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[2]['id'] ?>">
            <?= $articulos[2]['titulo']; ?>
          </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="spctcls">
      <div class="artc_cnt">
        <a href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[3]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[3]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[3]['id'] ?>">
          <div class="artc_foto">
            <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulos[3]['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
          </div>
          <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulos[3]['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulos[3]['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulos[3]['id'] ?>">
            <?= $articulos[3]['titulo']; ?>
          </a>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's working OK but I want to make it lightweight.

Thank You for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of easy really:

```
<?php foreach ($articulos as $articulo) { ?>
      <div class="spctcls">
          <div class="artc_cnt">
            <a class="art_liga" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulo['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulo['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulo['id'] ?>">
              <div class="artc_foto">
                <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulo['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
              </div>
              <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulo['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulo['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulo['id'] ?>">
                <?= $articulo['titulo']; ?>
              </a>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ooo I  see now. Can I substitute one of the elements inside parentheses tom somemeting like $count limit to 4?

Comment: Ok... I did it... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need to ask, how is it that in the loop the square brackets with the number that corresponds to the array position don't appear?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Farkie the rest was easy, To limit the amount of results this is how the whole thing ended up.

```
    <?php
    $i="1";
     foreach ($articulos as $articulo) { ?>
          <div class="spctcls">
              <div class="artc_cnt">
                <a class="art_liga" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulo['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulo['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulo['id'] ?>">
                  <div class="artc_foto">
                    <img src="img/chica/<?= $articulo['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
                  </div>
                  <a class="art_titl" href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articulo['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articulo['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articulo['id'] ?>">
                    <?= $articulo['titulo']; ?>
                  </a>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
    <?php
    if ($i++ == 4) break;
    } ?>
```

Thank You so much.